# Sequential Group By using data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have the following data set as data.table (dt):

```
                   time    wea
1   2016-06-16 00:04:50 cloudy
2   2016-06-16 02:14:55 cloudy
3   2016-06-16 03:19:04 cloudy
4   2016-06-16 04:19:24 cloudy
5   2016-06-16 05:23:45 cloudy
6   2016-06-16 06:25:05 cloudy
7   2016-06-16 07:26:46 cloudy
8   2016-06-16 08:27:06 cloudy
9   2016-06-16 09:34:09 sunny
10  2016-06-16 10:36:29 sunny
11  2016-06-16 11:39:09 sunny
12  2016-06-16 12:39:29 sunny
13  2016-06-16 13:44:50 rainy
14  2016-06-16 14:46:31 rainy
15  2016-06-16 15:47:12 rainy
16  2016-06-16 16:48:12 rainy
17  2016-06-16 17:49:54 sunny
18  2016-06-16 18:50:34 sunny
19  2016-06-16 19:51:34 cloudy
20  2016-06-16 20:53:55 cloudy
21  2016-06-16 21:56:51 cloudy
22  2016-06-16 22:30:42 cloudy
23  2016-06-16 23:26:14 cloudy
```

And I want this:

```
   wea start.point end.point
1:  cloudy           1      8
2:  sunny         9       12
3:  rainy         13       16
4:  sunny         17       18
5:  cloudy         19       23
```

I tried running the following, but without success

```
 dt[, .(start.point = head(.I,1), end.point = tail(.I,1)) , by="wea"]
```

because "by" groups the 2nd 'cloudy' block together with the first 'cloudy' block but I want to separate the consecutive blocks.

Comment: It's generally best to explain in words what you want as well, instead of just showing desired output.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use the `.I` to create an index and `rleid` in the `by` statement to separate the consequetive parts. Using:

```
dt[, .(start.point = .I[1], end.point = .I[.N]), by = .(wea, rleid(wea))
   ][, rleid := NULL][]
```

gives:

```
      wea start.point end.point
1: cloudy           1         8
2:  sunny           9        12
3:  rainy          13        16
4:  sunny          17        18
5: cloudy          19        23
```

Comment: I did not know the function `rleid`. It is working well. Thanks!!